# How to combine these wgets?

Tags: wget

I want to download many filetypes .dat, .hea, ... 
I did not find any piece of evidence for the structure `-A ".dat|.hea"`. 
Commands

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".dat" https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".hea" https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".hea-" https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".hea--" https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".xws" https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".atr" https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".atr-" https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/
```

Debian: 8.5
Wget: GNU Wget 1.16 built on linux-gnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-A` and `-R` options take a comma separated list.

e.g.

```
wget -r -R -l1 --no-parent -A ".dat,.haa,.hea-,.hea--,.xws,.atr,.atr-" https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/
```

From the man page

> -A acclist --accept acclist
>
> -R rejlist --reject rejlist
>
> Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject. Note that if any of the
> wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or
> rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.

Comment: That looks right but im on my phone and can't test atm

Comment: @Masi testing in my environment shows that it works on `GNU Wget 1.12`